CMake project builds with Github Actions with windows, but not Linux
I have a cmake project using vcpkg as my dependency manager that I would like to build using Github Actions, however I'm having trouble building the project for Linux. The project builds perfectly fine when targeting windows, and also builds on my windows 11 machine and ubuntu virtual machine.
Here is my .yml file:
name: Build
on:
  push:
jobs:
  build-linux:
    name: Build Project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      VCPKG_BINARY_SOURCES: "clear;x-gha,readwrite"
    steps:
      - name: Export GitHub Actions cache environment variables
        uses: actions/github-script@v7
        with:
          script: |
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_CACHE_URL', process.env.ACTIONS_CACHE_URL || '');
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN', process.env.ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN || '');

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.7

      - name: Run Setup
        run: |
          chmod +x ./setup.sh
          ./setup.sh

      - name: Configure and Build Project
        run: |
          cmake --build build --config Release

  build-windows:
    name: Build Project
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      VCPKG_BINARY_SOURCES: "clear;x-gha,readwrite"
    steps:
      - name: Export GitHub Actions cache environment variables
        uses: actions/github-script@v7
        with:
          script: |
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_CACHE_URL', process.env.ACTIONS_CACHE_URL || '');
            core.exportVariable('ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN', process.env.ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN || '');

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.7

      - name: Install Packages
        run: |
          git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
          cd vcpkg
          bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
          vcpkg integrate install
          cd ..

      - name: Configure and Build Project
        run: |
          cmake -S . -B ./build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Wno-dev
          cmake --build build --config Release

      - name: Generate Installer
        run: |
          choco install innosetup
          C:/"Program Files (x86)"/"Inno Setup 6"/ISCC.exe windowsiss.iss

      - name: Archive production artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          path: D:\a\wpical\wpical\Output\mysetup.exe
          name: WPIcal


Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project(WPIcal)

include(cmake/modules/GenResources.cmake)
generate_resources(src/resources generated/main/cpp OV ov outlineviewer_resources_src)

if(WIN32)
    set(outlineviewer_rc src/win/outlineviewer.rc)
elseif(APPLE)
    set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE ov.icns)
    set(APP_ICON_MACOSX src/mac/ov.icns)
    set_source_files_properties(${APP_ICON_MACOSX} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources")
endif()

# Add include directories for the project
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include)

# Add subdirectories for external libraries
add_subdirectory(wpigui)
add_subdirectory(imgui)

# Find required packages
find_package(apriltag REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Ceres CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(glog REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)

# Add the executable and specify the source files
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/cpp/WPIcal.cpp 
    src/cpp/fieldcalibration.cpp 
    src/cpp/cameracalibration.cpp
    ${outlineviewer_resources_src}
    ${outlineviewer_rc}
)

# Include directories
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include
)

# Link the libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    wpigui
    imgui
    apriltag::apriltag
    Eigen3::Eigen
    Ceres::ceres
    nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
    glog::glog
    Python3::Python
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)

if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE YES)
elseif(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE YES OUTPUT_NAME "WPIcal")
endif()

and this is the error I am getting, which occurs when vcpkg attempts to install the release version of opencv:
-- Building x64-linux-rel
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
    Command failed: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build . --config Release --target install -- -v -j5
    Working Directory: /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/x64-linux-rel
    See logs for more information:
      /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/install-x64-linux-rel-out.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  ports/opencv4/portfile.cmake:508 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)
error: building opencv4:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILEDSee https://learn.microsoft.com/vcpkg/troubleshoot/build-failures?WT.mc_id=vcpkg_inproduct_cli for more information.
Elapsed time to handle opencv4:x64-linux: 15 min
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+opencv4
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=[opencv4]+Build+error+on+x64-linux&body=Copy+issue+body+from+%2Fhome%2Frunner%2Fwork%2Fwpical%2Fwpical%2Fvcpkg_installed%2Fvcpkg%2Fissue_body.md
You can also submit an issue by running (GitHub CLI must be installed):
  gh issue create -R microsoft/vcpkg --title "[opencv4] Build failure on x64-linux" --body-file /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/issue_body.md
-- Running vcpkg install - failed
CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:902 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg-manifest-install.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:143 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The issue seems to occur when installing the opencv dependency. This happens every time I have tried to build it, at this same spot in the build process. vcpkg always is able to build the debug version of opencv, but not the release version, where it errors out.
I have made sure that vcpkg and cmake are fully up to date.
Here is the github repo: https://github.com/ElliotScher/wpical
I'm very confused as to why my project would build locally, but not on github actions. Furthermore, I don't understand why it builds on github actions for windows, but not for linux.
If anyone could help me that would be great. Thanks!

Hi! I suppose a good step would be to print /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/install-x64-linux-rel-out.log, since the ci output suggests the error info is to be found in there.

@Wutz Ok, thanks, How can I print the contents of the file with github actions? If I try to make it an artifact, the build fails before it reaches that step.

Not sure, you might be able to just cat it, if you make sure the actual build command doesn't abort the script. As in: cmake --build build --config Release || true followed by cat /home/runner/work/wpical/wpical/vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/install-x64-linux-rel-out.log. I'm honestly guessing here, I don't know if this will work in GH CI. But surely someone faced the issue of "get log after failed CI step" before, so a search should hopefully help you.
